# Magento - Path to product_collection.phtml?

Tags: magento

in my template `app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

I can see this code:

```
<?php if($product_collection_path = Mage::helper("ves_tempcp/framework")->getLayoutPath("product_collection.phtml")) { ?>
<?php require ($product_collection_path); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Where do I find product_collection.phtml? I can not see it in the /template/ folder...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the helper and layout path defined it must be in here: `app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/common/product_collection.phtml`